# Getting profile picture image from twitter using Parse twitter login for android

Tags: android, image, twitter

I'm quite new to android.

I'm using Parse as Baas for Twitter Authentication so as far as i know, i can only get a com.parse.twitter.Twitter object not a twitter4j.Twitter object.

I'm trying to download and display a profile picture image from twitter in an android app with this code:

```
String twitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?screen_name=myScreenName";
```

//according to the doc here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/profile_banner

And then i would like to use Picasso
                                    Picasso.with(aView.getContext()).load(twitterURL).resize(100,150).centerCrop().into(imageView);

But nothing is displayed...

I have also tried with that code:

```
URL url = new URL(twitterURL);
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
```

But getting error FileNotFoundException.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What do you get back from the API call? As far as I know, you need to authenticate with Twitter for all API calls and you don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I authenticate on my login page with a twitter account. At that moment, i save in my Parse database the screenName of the user in order to get later his profile picture with the above code. When i use the InputStream code, i get a FileNotFoundException. With Picasso, no exception is thrown. Maybe, the fact that i authenticate on the firts screen is not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem myself and never found a good answer, so your code helped me figure it out!

The InputStream you are fetching is actually in JSON format (e.g. {"id":4646546,"name":"ian","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1138330557/ian-straw_normal.jpg"}). So you can't just create a drawable from it. The Twitter API doc gives an example result: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show.

You can get rid of the '_normal' if you want to fetch the image in it's original size.

Using this profile_image_url, you can fetch the image you are interested in. You can use Android Query or Picasso to do this. You could also do another HttpRequest as long as you don't do it on the main UI thread.

You code becomes (i neglected the try/catch blocks for readability):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet verifyGet = new HttpGet(
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + handle);
ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(verifyGet);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(verifyGet);
InputStream is = response.getEntity.getContent();
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(is));
url = responseJson.getString("profile_image_url");

final AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);
//fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
androidQuery.id(R.id.image1).image(url);
```

Note: AQuery gives you many more options. You can fetch the image directly in a bitmap if you want. See: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI#Bitmap

Comment: it works!! you are a genius!! thanks a lot ian. I just had to take this code and to add apache commons to use IOUtils.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this myself but I believe it should point you in the right direction.

The Twitter API now requires you to be authenticated for each API request that is made.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet verifyGet = new HttpGet(
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?screen_name=myScreenName");
ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(verifyGet);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(verifyGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

So I think you had two issues:

1. You don't seem to be making any HTTP request, you were just creating the URL.
2. You weren't signing the Twitter request

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#twitterusers-requests

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tested your solution. It seems to be a very intersting direction (The link seems to say that too).But still no image is displayed. The InpuStream is not null but i can't say that there ise a pciture inside. So I try to convert the InputStream into a drawable like that: Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");                       imageView.setImageDrawable(d);                                       But the object d is still null..

Comment: No one had the same problem??